# How to set Principal using OAuth 2.0 / OWIN / JWT?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, jwt, owin

I was using the basic OAuth Bearer token stuf baked into the latest Web API project, and all was fine. I was able to get a token, and pass it back to the Web API and have it authenticate me and populate the ClaimsPrincipal. I could then get authorized on the API calls, and I used the ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute (from Thinktecture.IdentityModel) and I checked against policies in my web.config.

However, I wanted to try to use a JWT instead of the standard OAuth token, and now I can't get it to work. It validates the JWT just fine, and it returns the ClaimsPrincipal from the validation code, but it never gets set for the current user, so the authorization code on the api fails because there are no claims.

I changed my Startup.Auth.cs to contain the following, with the only difference between this code and the previous working version being that I pass in MyCustomJwtFormat() token format class instead of the original:

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            AllowInsecureHttp = false,
            AccessTokenFormat = new MyCustomJwtFormat(audience, new X509CertificateSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, CertStoreStuff.GetCertificateFromStore("CN=XXXXXXX"))), 
            AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active
        };
```

The MyCustomJwtFormat class implements `ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>`, and the unprotect() method successfully returns a populated ClaimsIdentity.

Is there some manual step I have to take when using JWT in order to set the Principal?

Comment: I've noticed that I am getting this warning in the debug output: "Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware Warning: 0 : invalid bearer token received" after MyCustomJwtFormat.protect() method completes, even though it has authenticated the token and sent back what appears to be a perfectly good AuthenticationTicket. So, despite the fact that my protect() method seems to be working fine, I'm still getting something wrong. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this Chris?

Comment: @ChrisC did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Sorry @Daniel, this was so long ago and I think I changed path completely on this at some point as this code doesn't seem to exist at all in my solution anymore. Ultimately, I ended up using UseOAuthBearerAuthentication, and using IdentityServer libraries to send the JWT token from the Web API consumer. Doesn't seem like I needed much custom code after all.

Comment: @ChrisC Do you have a repo I can take a look at? Getting the same error